# Finding encrypted SQL database instances in our SQL Server Estate

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Is there a quick way to find SQL Server instances across our whole SQL Estate that hold encrypted (SQL TDE) whole databases or database table columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DbaTools' Powershell module, which has a command [`Get-DbaDatabase`](https://docs.dbatools.io/Get-DbaDatabase.html)

```
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance SomeServer -Encrypted
```

You can even find all servers using `Find-DbaInstance`

```
Find-DbaInstance `
  -DiscoveryType IPRange `
  -IpAddress "10.1.1.0/24" `
| Get-DbaDatabase -Encrypted;
```

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, this is helpful, as it can be run from our management server, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Quick -- that would depend. But if it were me, I'd set up a central management server and register all your SQL Servers there.

There's a really good introduction to the feature here:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/tools-sql-server/registered-servers-and-central-management-server-stores/

Then all you need to do is run a query against all the registered servers like the one below:

```
select name, is_encrypted from sys.databases
```

Query sys.columns to look for encrypted columns

So it requires an investment to create the central management server but will make you many times more effective as a DBA from that point forward.

Comment: Query sys.columns to look for encrypted columns

Comment: You can just edit further details into your answer instead of adding them as comments.

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64, that makes sense. Thank you for your time and response.